# problem in reading <TITLE> tag from web page in java

Tags: java, jtidy

I am using jtidy parser to parse the web page. It is working, sort of:

```
InputStream in=new URL("http://www.medicinenet.com/alopecia_areata/article.htm").openStream();
Document doc= new Tidy().parseDOM(in, null);
String titleText=doc.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

It is working fine for `<title>...</title>`, but the url which I passed, it contains title tag `<TITLE>...</TITLE>` in capital letter. So it is returning null.

How to read `<TITLE>...</TITLE>` & `<title>...</title>` in one statement using java code? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Just check for null, then check uppercase

```
String titleText=doc.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
if (titleText == null) titleText=doc.getElementsByTagName("TITLE").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

`getElementsByTagName` is case sensitive, so this is the simplest option.

Comment: I tried above code,but this is not working,please help me with another solution

Comment: I tried this code as you said---> if (titleText == null) titleText=doc.getElementsByTagName("TITLE").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();----------it is throwing exception,again it is returning null.

Comment: is the title tag in mixed case...e,g <Title>

Comment: no,it is not in mixed case,it is in capital letter,'<TITLE>'.